# My kendogrid export functionality is not working properly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I want to export the kendo grid data to excel on button click.I have tried that one,it's working but it exports only one page data and footer also exported.But i want to export total grid data without footer.

my code is

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + document.getElementById('grid').outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: here isthe fiddle       http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/

Comment: Is it possible to change the file name. When I click on export button I am  getting file name  download.xls instead can we change this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is exporting the `outerHTML` of the grid. This of course includes all HTML (header, footer, data etc.). Since you have paging enabled the grid HTML will include only the current page of data.

Also after checking your fiddle it seems that you are using serverPaging which means you don't have all the data to begin with. You need to disable serverPaging if you want to have all data. Then create the HTML of the grid by traversing the result of the [data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data)() method of the data source.

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {

     var data = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
     var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";

     result += "<table><tr><th>OrderID</th><th>Freight</th><th>Order Date</th><th>Ship Name</th><th>Ship City</th></tr>";

     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         result += "<tr>";

         result += "<td>";
         result += data[i].OrderID;
         result += "</td>";

         result += "<td>";
         result += data[i].Freight;
         result += "</td>";

         result += "<td>";
         result += kendo.format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", data[i].OrderDate);
         result += "</td>";

         result += "<td>";
         result += data[i].ShipName;
         result += "</td>";

         result += "<td>";
         result += data[i].ShipCity;
         result += "</td>";

         result += "</tr>";
     }

     result += "</table>";
     window.open(result);

     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/4/

Comment: ya its working fine thank you so much,but here issue is while filtering the grid then also its export all the records.I want to export all data records in page-load and if data is filtered need to export only filter data.

Comment: Please help me.I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: You need to create a new data source and use it instead:

var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource( {
   data: dataSource.data(),
   filter: dataSource.filter()
});

var data = filteredDataSource.data();

Comment: ya,I am tried that one but only table headers are exported.here is the fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/8/

Comment: Try calling filteredDataSource.read() before filteredDataSource.data().

Comment: Thank you for your quick responding,I tried that one but when we filtered the grid then also exporting all the grid data.here is the fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/10/

Comment: Damn ... You need to use view() instead of data(). Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/11/

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time.